# How to concatenate two values from different columns into a single column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have dataframe, where there are two string columns, which need to be concatenated to a single column

There are 3 values in 2 columns.

1.Column Comment_vol consists of Blank,Pass and VolA

2.Column Comment_wt consists of wtA,Pass

Now I need a column where,

1. When there is blank in Column Comment_vol and any value in Column Comment wt, it should take value in comment_wt column and vise vsersa
2. When there is Pass in both column values, it should take Pass
3. And if there is both VolA and wtA, it should take both

Input :

```
  Comment_vol    Comment_wt     
  Pass           wtA            
                 Pass            
  VolA           Pass           
  Pass           Pass           
                 wtA            
  VolA           wtA
```

Output:

```
  Comment_vol    Comment_wt     Comment_final
  Pass           wtA            wtA
                 Pass           Pass 
  VolA           Pass           VolA
  Pass           Pass           Pass
                 wtA            wtA
  VolA           wtA            VolA, WtA
```

Code:

```
 df['Comment'] = df['comment_vol'].str.cat(df['comment_wt'], sep =" ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def concatcolumns(x):
    vol = str(x[0])
    wt = str(x[1])
    if vol in ['nan', 'Pass']:
        return wt
    elif wt == 'Pass':
        return vol
    else:
        return ", ".join(x)

df['Comment'] = df[['Comment_vol', 'Comment_wt']].apply(lambda x: concatcolumns(x),axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: *add explanation*

`df.Comment_vol.str.strip().isin(['Pass', ''])` to strip any front and back white spaces and uses `isin` to check whether values in column `Comment_vol` is either 'Pass' or ''. I use `strip` to make sure if your data has words such as ' Pass' or 'VolA   ' (notice the front and back white spaces), it still works. This returns a boolean series, `True` on 'Pass' or '', else `False`. Assign this to `n`

`df.Comment_wt.str.strip().isin(['Pass', ''])` is the same but applying to column `Comment_wt` and assign to `m`

`'~'` is negation operator, `~n` means any word neither 'Pass' nor '' in `Comment_vol`

`np.select([n, ~n & m], [df.Comment_wt, df.Commnt_vol], df.Comment_vol.str.cat(df.Comment_wt, sep=', '))` is equivalent to the logic

```
if n:
    df.Comment_wt
elif ~n & m: #`Comment_vol` is NOT 'Pass' or '' and  df.Comment_wt is 'Pass' or ''
    df.Commnt_vol
else:
    df.Comment_vol.str.cat(df.Comment_wt, sep=', ') #concat both columns using `,'
```

this `np.select` returns the array as follows:

```
np.select([n, ~n & m], [df.Comment_wt, df.Comment_vol], df.Comment_vol.str.cat(df.Comment_wt, sep=', '))

Out[350]: array(['wtA', 'Pass', 'VolA', 'Pass', 'wtA', 'VolA, wtA'], dtype=objec
t)
```

this array is used to create `Comment_final` columns of `df`

You may read the doc of `np.select` for more info https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html

---

**Original:**
If I understand correctly your description and output, this is a classic case of using `np.select`

```
n = df.Comment_vol.str.strip().isin(['Pass', ''])
m = df.Comment_wt.str.strip().isin(['Pass', ''])

df['Comment_final'] = np.select([n, ~n & m], [df.Comment_wt, df.Comment_vol], df.Comment_vol.str.cat(df.Comment_wt, sep=', '))


Out[591]:
  Comment_vol Comment_wt Comment_final
0        Pass        wtA           wtA
1                   Pass          Pass
2        VolA       Pass          VolA
3        Pass       Pass          Pass
4                    wtA           wtA
5        VolA        wtA     VolA, wtA
```

Comment: Could you explain the code, since i'm pretty new to this

Comment: Thank you for the explanation